# How to trigger an "onchange" for only first two chars of an element value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some Code to filter the first two chars of an text input. So the main aspect is, to call a controller function which gets the values of these two chars. I want to trigger that function only, if one of these two chars change.

```
$("#selector").on("keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
        var firstChar = $(this).val().charAt(0);
        var secondChar = $(this).val().charAt(1);
        var length = 0;
        firstChar.val().on("change", function () {
            some Ajax
        });
        secondChar.val().on("change", function () {
            some Ajax                
        });
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the old value and compare the first two characters when the input has been changed.

```js
var selector = $("#selector");
var oldValue = selector.val();

selector.on("change", function() {
  if (this.value.charAt(0) !== oldValue.charAt(0)) console.log(1);
  if (this.value.charAt(1) !== oldValue.charAt(1)) console.log(2);
  oldValue = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selector" />
```

If you want the event to get triggered right after each character is changed, then you could use a `keydown` event with a `setTimeout` of `0ms` so that the keydown will bubble up and actually the change the value.

```js
var selector = $("#selector");
var oldValue = selector.val();

selector.on("change", onChange);
selector.on("keydown", function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    onChange.call(self);
  }, 0);
});

function onChange() {
  if (this.value.charAt(0) !== oldValue.charAt(0)) console.log(1);
  if (this.value.charAt(1) !== oldValue.charAt(1)) console.log(2);
  oldValue = this.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selector" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I used that idea of just comparing the old value with the new one and it works. Thanks!